# como obtener la fecha maxima y minima de un query en jpa con java?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jpa

Tengo el siguiente query

```
@NamedQuery(name = "findRegistroAccesoByNuserid", query = "select myRegistroAcceso from RegistroAcceso myRegistroAcceso where myRegistroAcceso.nuserid = ?1 and TO_CHAR(myRegistroAcceso.fecRegistroEntrada, 'dd/MM/yyyy') =  ?2")
```

que me regresa registros de acuerdo a una fecha y un id que le paso como parametro para que haga el filtrado, ese query se lo paso a una lista

```
listRegistroAcceso = registroAccesoService.findRegistroAccesoByNuserid(cvePersona, strFecha);

    for (RegistroAcceso registroAcceso1 : listRegistroAcceso) {

        horaEntradaBiometrico = registroAcceso1.getFecRegistroEntrada();
        System.out.println("PRUEBA ENTRADA" +registroAcceso1.getFecRegistroEntrada());


    }
```

hay un campo llamado fecRegistroEntrada, que quiero extraer de esa lista
y me pinta lo siguiente en consola

```html
PRUEBA ENTRADA2015-03-06 14:05:50.0
PRUEBA ENTRADA2015-03-06 14:05:54.0
PRUEBA ENTRADA2015-03-06 14:05:58.0
```

Ahora solamente necesito pintar en una tabla el primer registro que pinta 
que es el "PRUEBA ENTRADA2015-03-06 14:05:50.0" y el ultimo "PRUEBA ENTRADA2015-03-06 14:05:58.0" o sea sacar el min y el max se podria decir, hice una variable llamada horaEntradaBiometrico, pero a la hora de pintarla en la tabla me toma el ultimo valor 
como le puedo hacer para obtener esas dos fechas y poder mostarlas?

Answer (score 0):

Si tu aplicacion no requiere mucho performance podrias usar un union y solo cambiar el query de la siguiente manera:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "findRegistroAccesoByNuserid", query = "select * from (select MIN(myRegistroAcceso) fecha from RegistroAcceso myRegistroAcceso where myRegistroAcceso.nuserid = ?1 and TO_CHAR(myRegistroAcceso.fecRegistroEntrada, 'dd/MM/yyyy') =  ?2 UNION select MAX(myRegistroAcceso)fecha from RegistroAcceso myRegistroAcceso where myRegistroAcceso.nuserid = ?1 and TO_CHAR(myRegistroAcceso.fecRegistroEntrada, 'dd/MM/yyyy') =  ?2) where fecha is not null" )
```

Asi obtendrias la fecha minima y la fecha maxima en un solo query.